# Could it make sense to schedule an export of SQL database to NoSQL for graphical data mining?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, graph-databases, extract, nosql

Would it make sense for me to schedule an export my SQL database to a graph database (such as Neo4j) in order to generate interactive graphics of relationships such as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=167&v=NcYJhzFKyfw)?

**UPDATE:** Or by extension, should I even be looking to move over to a graph database altogeher?

My graphical database would not need to be a live reflection of the relational database - an extract every few days would be more than sufficient.

In my case, I currently have a relational database (MySQL) where I’m recording stock items as they pass between individuals/depots. The concept is as follows:

**Items:**

```
STOCKID DISPATCHDATE
0001    2014-01-01
0002    2015-06-03
```

**Individuals:**

```
USERID FIRSTNAME
0001   Tom
0002   Jones
```

**Depots:**

```
DEPOTID ZIPCODE
0001    50421
0002    71028
```

**Owners:**

```
STOCK_ID USER_ID RECEIVED   DISPATCHED
0001     0001    2015-05-01 2015-05-10
0001     0002    2015-05-11 2015-05-20
```

From the NoSQL database I would like to be able to visually see things such as:

- The flow of which people an item has passed through (and dates of each relationship)
- Which items are at each individual/depot (on a given date)
- Which individuals are at which depots (on a given date)

Comment: If something reduces your work, helps you organize better, isolates functionality or simply makes things easier for you - then yes, of course it makes sense. We have tools to use them, so if you used two tools to help yourself or your users - that's awesome and that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and encouraging feedback....I guess the question that I couldn't quite put my finger on (I will update the question now) is should I, for example, be changing my production database to Neo4j rather than extracting one from a relational database every few days

Comment: The way you should organize this is up to you. Nothing prevents you from inserting into relational database and NoSQL at the same time. I'm assuming you have certain code that deals with populating database(s) with info - why not insert into both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As N.B. says in the comments, if the tool is useful then use it - worst case is you find that the tool isn't useful after all and you stop using it (having wasted some time in setting it up, but such is life).

In general, there are three ways to sync the database:

1. [Two Phase Commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol): modify MySql in one transaction, modify Neo4j in another transaction, if either transaction fails then you roll back both transactions; the transactions don't commit until both signal that they can be committed.  This provides the highest data integrity but is very expensive.
2. Loosely synchronized transactions: modify MySql in one transaction, modify Neo4j in another transaction, if one succeeds and the other fails then retry the failed transaction a few times, and if it still fails then decide what to do (e.g. undo the successful transaction, which is complicated by the fact that the transaction has already committed and the values may have been used; or log the error and ask for a database administrator to manually sync the databases; or third option).  This offers decent data integrity and is cheaper than two phase commit, but is more difficult to recover from if something goes horribly wrong.
3. Batch synchronization: modify MySql, and then after a time interval (five minutes, an hour, whatever's appropriate) you sync the changes with Neo4j based on a row version number or a timestamp (note that it's not much of a problem if you sync a bit too much data since you'll just be overwriting a value with the same value, so err on the side of syncing too much per batch).  This solution is easy to program, and is appropriate if Neo4j doesn't need the latest and greatest data.

I worked on a similar project where we were syncing MySql with a key-value nosql database (caching expensive queries), using loosely synchronized transactions.  We wrote a customized `Transaction` wrapper that contained a concurrent queue of side-effects (i.e. changes to be made to the key-value database); if the MySql transaction succeeded then we committed all of the side-effects in the queue to the key-value database (with three retries in the case of transient network failure, after which we logged the error, invalidated the key-value database entry which would result in a fallback to MySql, and notified a database admin - this happened one time when the key-value database crashed for an extended period, and was solved by running a batch synchronization), else we discarded them.

Answer (score 0):

I think before starting with the migration there are some questions worth asking yourself:

- Can I do the graphical representation without migrating/adding a new data source (using MySQL)?
- What degree of efficiency do I want when using such graphical interface?
- How easy would it be, in case, to add a new data source?

What you see in that video is done by a visual component on some data from either databases or flat files, so I'd say that the answer to the first question it's likely to be yes.

Depending on how many people and the kind of user it's going to use such graphical representation (internal or external, analyst or not, etc...) this can be another driver for the decision.

About the third question, without writing a duplicate of the other answer, I think @Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot already covered it. As usual, with many data sources the problem is always to keep things in sync together and the entity resolution problem (which you minimise using the same dataset).

In my experience what Neo4J is very good at is "pattern" querying: given a specific network pattern (drawn with the Cypher language) it will apply and find it to the network dataset.
When it's about neighbours querying also a SQL solution, in small projects, can achieve the same result without too many problems. Of course if your solution has to scale to hundreds analysts and hundred of thousands queries per day consider to move.

Anyway, given your dataset it looks to me that you are working on a time-based type of data. In this kind of scenarios it could be worth to have a look at the dynamical behaviour of your network to find also temporal pattern, more than simple network ones.
From the same author of the video you've posted have also a look at this other [graphical representation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDR-iU5msWg&noredirect=1).

In case you want to model a time based graph just note that there's not a bullet proof solution with any data source yet.

[Here's a Neo4J tutorial](http://keylines.com/network-visualization/visualize-neo4j-time-graph) on your to model and represent the data in case of a time based dataset.
I bet you can do similar things also with MySQL (probably with less efficiency and elegance in querying) but I haven't done it myself yet to give some numbers - maybe someone else did it and can add some benchmarks here.

**Disclaimer**: I work in the KeyLines team.